# preemptible VM's in managed instance group go into terminated state

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, preemption

I have a Managed Instance Group made up of a set of preemptible VM's - they are ephemeral and can be preempted anytime (our group is large enough to sustain losing several VM's at once) - for the most part the MIG will bring the VM count back up to the desired level on VM preemption - occasionally a node goes into the terminated state and the MIG still counts it as available and does nothing to correct the issue - so I am down a one or more vms.  My understanding of the terminated state is that "TERMINATED. A user shut down the instance, or the instance encountered a failure. You can choose to restart the instance or delete it".  Given that we didnt shut the instance down it must have encountered some failure - logs dont indicate anything other than the node was pre-empted.  How can I configure my instance group to delete/recreate VM's that end up in this state?

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I understand that you want to know why VM's terminated all the time right?
As you mentioned that you are using a Managed Instance Group with **preemptible** VM's, this means that the VM's are always terminated in 24 hours (or less) according to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups#groups_of_preemptible_instances).

Other than that, maybe you want to be sure what happened on your instance in the last hours, for that I recommend you to open SSH in your instance and use "journalctl" as example:

```
journalctl -b --since "2021-03-04 00:00:00" | grep 'terminated'
```

This command will look for all the "terminated" statements from the given timestamp to the moment you run the command.

If you don't care about the termination or your VM's every 24 hours I don't see a problem of using [preemptible VM's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#limitations). But if this is causing you problems in your operation I would suggest you to turn off the preemptible feature and let the [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/adding-an-instance-group-to-a-load-balancer) to act according your needs.

Jose.

Comment: I see it as more of an issue with the Managed Instance Group. I dont care that they get pre-empted (it > 1/24 hrs due to tight resources in the google data center I use).  The scenerio goes like this:  I have 20 VMs in an Instance group - 1 gets pre-empted (deleted) and the IG drops to 19 - but its suppose to be 20 so the IG creates a new VM to bring it back up - all good.  EXCEPT this new VM comes up and then terminates (it may try a few times and get pre-empted again) - this is my issue the IG thinks I have 20 VM but 1 is terminated so I really only have 19 - this repeats over time.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Stateful MIGs][1]? This could be the right option for the project you are working on. I'm not sure if you tried the "journactl" command I suggested you on past answer, this could help you to find out why your instances are terminating.


[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs#when_to_use_stateful_migs